# Newb over head: Why is my home made screen recorder crashing?(c# and windows forms)

Tags: c#, video, screenshot

[SOLVED] Ofir's solution worked right out of the box. Currently running for five minutes at 24 f/s.

I'm trying to save images from the screen.

Basically my issue, is that as I decrease Thread.sleep (to create a decent frame rate) the program crashes. The program crashes faster the closer thread.sleep is to 0, but I can't even find the problem because I've never dealt with this kind of stuff(If it was unity3d I'd be all over this).

```
void ScreenCapture()//this is from a youtube tutorial
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Bitmap bm = new Bitmap((int)Math.Round(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width * 1.5), (int)Math.Round(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height * 1.5));
    //I don't know why I had to multipyly these by 1.5, but it made the screen fit properly.
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bm);
            g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bm.Size);
            pictureBox.Image = bm;
            Thread.Sleep(250);
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(ScreenCapture);
        t.Start();
    }
```

I've got some sweet sweet errors coming your way too.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

error code: -2147467259

and I built a try-catch(which I know little about) but it breaks too after a few tests, lemme see if I can get that log.

```
    System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(0x80004005): The operation completed successfully as System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen(Int32 sourceX, Int32 sourceY, Int32 destinationX,Int32 destinationY, Size blockRegionSize)
 at Screen_Recorder.Form1.ScreenCapture() in C:Users\Jupiter\Desktop\visual studio experiments\Screen Recorder\ScreenRecorder\Form1.cs:line 35
```

if I then click ok it says:

```
System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.
 at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Int32 width, Int32 height, PixelFormat format)
 at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(int32 width, Int32 height)
 at Screen_Recorder.Form1.ScreenCapture() C:Users\Jupiter\Desktop\visual studio experiments\Screen Recorder\ScreenRecorder\Form1.cs:line 32
```

and then it will repeat that error ad infinitum.

Anyway, I'm going to bed and then I'll get into it again tommorrow, but any advice before then would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a memory leak.

`Graphics` and `Bitmap` are disposable object and should be disposed when you've done with them.
You can only put the `Graphics` in your case in a `using` block and the last bitmap should be disposed every iteration of the loop.
Therefore, your code should look like this:

```
private void ScreenCapture()
{
    while (true)
    {
        var bm = new Bitmap((int)Math.Round(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width * 1.5), 
                           (int)Math.Round(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height * 1.5));
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bm)) g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bm.Size);

        // As per the comment by HansPassant - the following would cause
        // a thread race with the UI thread.
        //this.pictureBox1.Image?.Dispose();
        //this.pictureBox1.Image = bm;

        // Instead we use beginInvoke to run this on the UI thread
        Action action = () =>
            {
                this.pictureBox1.Image?.Dispose();
                this.pictureBox1.Image = bm;
            };

        this.BeginInvoke(action);

        Thread.Sleep(250);
    }
}
```

This loop is never going to end (because of the `while (true)`), Maybe you should consider adding a `CancelationToken` and use `Task` instead of a `Thread`.

And one last thing, you should dispose the picturebox itself as well after finishing with it.

Comment: It is one reason, a very common reason, but not the only one.  The Image property is not thread-safe and calling Dispose() at the same time the UI thread is painting the image will not come to a good end.  Much lower odds for failure, but not zero and thus much harder to debug.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not sure i understood you completely, but what if we save a reference to the Image, set the new Image and then dispose the old one? would that solve the issue?

Comment: No, that is still a threading race since the Paint() method might be in flight and is using the old reference.  Cold hard fact is that you must use BeginInvoke() so the code runs on the UI thread.

Comment: Or maybe invoke that part?

Comment: It is the Image property assignment and the Dispose call that must run on the UI thread.  An additional concern is a firehose problem, occurs when the worker thread creates bitmaps faster than the UI thread can display them.  But that is easily identified, the OP will see the UI thread getting unresponsive.

Comment: Thanks everybody! I thought this was simple. I knew that garbage collection was the answer but I couldn't decipher my debug errors. I'll let all these comments sink in and try to fix it (alot of the terms in these solutions are foreign to me). I'll mark the thread as closed once it's fixed.